# Firebase aggregated and average engagement time mismatch

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

Unable to understand the average figure compared with the number which we see on the graph. Take for instance average engagement time -- what you see on the graph is mostly less than 10 minutes, while the average number which you see on top is > 16m. We are unable to tie these two data points together. We are seeing similar variation for the other 2 buckets i.e. engaged session per user and average engagement time per session. Can anyone help with this?

[image]